# When does having the measure of *any* set with property $R$ be zero imply that the measure of set of *all* subsets satisfying property $R$ is zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's say we start removing random open sub-intervals from the unit interval by picking a point in the remaining (unremoved) area, creating a 1-d "ball" around that point with maximum radius that still fits within the remaining length, and removing all those points (and repeating this indefinitely).

Intuitively, it seems for any fixed subset of length $L<1$ it is almost certain that a point will fall close enough to this subset to remove it.

Therefore, this process must converge to some subset of zero length.

My question is whether that last sentence really follows from the previous one-- does having the measure of *any* set with property $R$ be zero imply that the measure of the set of *all* subsets satisfying property $R$ is zero?

Comment: Your last line (and the title) perhaps has a typo... what does it mean for a property (of all subsets satisfying property $R$) to be zero? Did you mean to say measure? In any case, you might also want to specify more the example procedure you have in mind for removing intervals; for example, if the "balls" have fixed length then you remove the entire interval in finitely many steps, so there's no probability needed (it obviously happens with probability $1$ as a result). If the size of the balls you are removing shrinks, then you need to specify how quickly.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks! yes, it was a typo. I'll add more details to the process.

Comment: While interpreting logical quantifiers, "any" is equivalent to "all".

Comment: @BrianMoehring thx — I’ve fixed — meant to say set of all such sets

Comment: I don't know how you can extend a measure from a $\sigma$-algebra to... maybe the power set of the $\sigma$-algebra?